# Using \qedhere automatically in every proof

Tags: amsmath, theorems

I'm currently using `\qedhere` at the end of my proof every time since I'm really satisfied with the positioning of the qed mark. The problem is, I use it so often that I want to make the qed mark always positioned as if I've used `\qedhere` WITHOUT typing `\qedhere` every time. I've searched here and there but couldn't find relevant information.

```
\begin{proof}
\mbox{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\[\Vert B^{-1}-A^{-1}\Vert =\Vert B^{-1}(A-B)A^{-1}\Vert\leq\Vert B^{-1}\Vert\Vert A-B\Vert\Vert A^{-1}\Vert\leq\frac{\beta}{\alpha (\alpha -\beta )}\]
Then one can see that $\Vert B^{-1}-A^{-1}\Vert\rightarrow 0$ as $\beta =\Vert B-A\Vert\rightarrow 0$
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
Lastly, we want to introduce another matrix norm. Let $A$ be a matrix representation of a linear function. Define
```

[image: Before \qedhere]
This is before `\qedhere`.

[image: After \qedhere]
This is after `\qedhere`.

(`enumerate` environment was inserted)

Some might say without `\qedhere` looks better, but I'm just writing down notes and organizing them so I don't want that space to be wasted. Sometimes it's less noticeable but I've yet not encounted a case where `\qedhere` caused a problem.

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: You need `\qedhere` only in special occasions: when the proof ends with a list (`enumerate`, `itemize` or `description`) or with a math display. Just remove `\qedhere` in that case and you'll see the tombstone in the right place.

Comment: I think even when the proof doesn't end with such environments, \qedhere looks better. Without it, sometimes it takes too much space. I'll upload the pictures.

Comment: I see the same result (first with `\qedhere`, second without it): [**picture**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VB2zm.png)

Comment: @TaxxiDriver, remember to check for blank lines before `\end{proof}`

Comment: Hm, I think I use a lot of enumerate or math display mode environment and if \qedhere doesn't change at all in other cases it's perfectly fine I think. Just automatically adding \qedhere would be fine for me unless the method brings confliction with other environments.

Comment: Please, add the code with which you produced the image.

Comment: @TaxxiDriver The macro `\end{proof}` is already equivalent to `\qedhere\end{proof}` in standard situations. Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), we can't really help you.

Comment: @TaxxiDriver, without explicit code, we cannot help. But do consider Bernards suggestion of using `ntheorem`

Comment: @TaxxiDriver I can't understand why “Lastly…” is before `\end{proof}` if it doesn't make part of the proof. The main point in `\qedhere` is that it's *not* generally needed, but you have to supply it if the proof ends with a list or a display. Extensively using lists in proof is, in my opinion, bad style.

Comment: @egreg That was a mistake, sorry. As I said, I'm organizing my notes more systematically so that I can understand as a whole. I'm not publishing this or something. That's why I put relevant theorems into one to make a big picture of it. I use it a lot, and it helps me a lot. Just putting down many theorems one by one is sometimes bad as well in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that very easily with `ntheorem`, which works well even if the proof ends up in a displayed equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

 \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}



\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
This theorem is awesome!
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
Because I can change the position of qed mark correctly!
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Another proof]
This is a very important proof.
\begin{align*}
    a & = b\\ c & = d.
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that there is **no display equation involved** in the screenshot posted by the OP.

Comment: At  the time I saw the question there was no example in the O.P.'s question. Anyway, he/she might be interested in being informed  `ntheorem` can manage such situations, don't you think?

Comment: I dunno. I don't like shooting in the darkness...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm currently working on this method. ntheorem indeed seems very useful.

Comment: Its main advantage is this automatic placement in (almost) all cases — and also the fact it is easier to customise than `amsthm`. It is also able to work with `thmtools`.